# build.dir error in netBeans

Tags: netbeans

I am working on my own, learning about Java servlets and JSPs.  My machine configuration as follows is from NetBeans' About page.

Product Version: NetBeans IDE 8.0.1 (Build 201408251540)

Updates: NetBeans IDE is updated to version NetBeans 8.0.1 Patch 1.1

Java: 1.8.0_20; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.20-b23

Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_20-b26

System: Windows 7 version 6.1 running on amd64; Cp1252; en_US (nb)

Tomcat 8.0.14 for Windows x64 is also installed as the web server.

I created a tiny web app yesterday, which was working as expected.  When I went to the next exercise in the book, it was necessary to install MySQL.  That seemed pretty straightforward, but alas, the install ran into a couple of problems.  Unfortunately, I had not created a restore point right before that attempt, so I went back to the restore point created before the Tomcat install.

I re-installed Tomcat, and as a sanity check, started it, started NetBeans, tried to the run the tiny web app and after removing the server and re-adding it (because I got an error about the server) in NetBeans, got a message that I needed to set the build.dir.

For a tiny app, this is just annoying, but when working on a large app, it would be nice to avoid this problem.  Another book author supplied app was working before, and is still working so...

Here are my questions:

1) Why/how would simply re-installing Tomcat cause a break in something that was working?

2) It seems as if the build.dir is set in build-impl.dir (in the app that is working) with a statement like (the opening and closing tags are missing so the statements would appear):
   property location="${build.dir}/empty" name="empty.dir"

One post I read somewhere said that the above statement should be before the:
   fail unless="build.dir">Must set build.dir

3) How/where is this build.dir set during the creation of a NetBeans web app?  Is there some dialog box that I'm not completing correctly?  If I miss it, is there a way to get back to it after the app gets "confused"?

Thanks in advance for any help on this.